# How to prepare data for t-test based on the experimentation

Tags: python, t-test

I have a problem understanding the practical use of the t-test in the following scenario.
I'm using python SciPy.stats library for the t-test. I've read articles and understand how it is supposed to work, but I still fail to apply it my use case.

I'm running an AB experiment and want to measure the impact my change has on the 2 metrics using t-test.

- Metric 1 - conversion. Visitors to buyers.
- Metric 2 - Revenue per visitor.

So, the reason I struggle is that at the end of the experiment I end up with 3 data sets split by A and B groups - Visitors, Buyers, Orders.

stat.ttest_ind requires 2 samples (for variants A and B) as an input. Could you explain what I should provide as an input for each of the metrics in this case?

I was thinking about the following way

1. Use bootstrap or another sampling technique for A and B and draw 100 samples from each population (A and B).
2. For each sample calculate avg conversion and avg revenue per visitor.
3. Use avg conversion (and avg revenue per visitor) distribution per sample as an input for the ttest_ind method.
4. At the end of it I should get t and p value for each metric

Is that the right way of using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed way is complicating things, and is likely to introduce some bias to the result of the $t$-test as you are not really computing what you should assume when running a $t$-test.

To use the SciPy $t$-test, what you need to provide is the *responses* of the groups to be compared, i.e. *everyone* in the A group and B group respectively (as they are considered samples instead of the population).

For the conversion metric, the responses for one group will be in the form of
$$[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...],$$ representing whether the corresponding visitor has bought something. For the revenue per visitor metric they should resemble something like
$$[0, 18.2, 27.3, 0, 0, 110.34, ...],$$ representing how much the corresponding visitor has spent.*

In a theoretical setup, these numbers would correspond to the samples $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$. They should be easily computable with the visitors, orders, and buyers datasets that you have.

---

* Illustrative example, there were no intention for the numbers in the two lists to match.

There are other considerations that are out of the scope of the question but worth bearing in mind nonetheless. For example, you should consider other types of t-test (e.g. Welch's) if the variance/sample size between the A and B group differs by quite a bit. Moreover, you should consider whether $t$-test is a good enough approximation for r.v. with binary responses - generally they are good enough for A/B tests on the Web, but the method might fall apart when you have an extremely low conversion rate.

Answer (score 0):

**For metric 1.**

Before the change (A): You have the proportion of visitors
who bought something. Maybe 635 buyers out of 2177 visitors over a certain period of time before the change. The proportion of conversions is about 34%.
Then after the change (B): Maybe you have 773 buyers out of 2013
visitors over a certain period of time after the change. The proportion
of conversions is about 38%.

Clearly 38% is somewhat better than 34%. The question is whether you have
enough visitors in each time period for this difference to be deemed
statistically significant at the 5% level. [With a few thousand visitors, $735/2177 \approx 0.34$ vs. $773/2013 \approx 0.38$ is very much more informative than, say, $17/50$ vs. $19/50$.]

There are various tests of binomial proportions. Variations have to do with how the variability is computed and whether continuity corrections are used for normal approximations of binomial by normal.) Here
are results from Minitab software from one of these tests, using my artificial data from above.
The P-value $0.002 < 0.05 = 5\%,$ so you could say that
the difference in proportions is significant at the 5% level
(even at the 1% level).

> Whether this is due to *your* change
> between 'before' and 'after' or to a general change in consumer behavior or change in
> the economy before vs. after, is hard to say. Passage of time is often a confounding issue in AB testing.

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample    X     N  Sample p
1       735  2177  0.337621
2       773  2013  0.384004

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.0463834
95% CI for difference:  (-0.0754698, -0.0172970)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  
   Z = -3.13  P-Value = 0.002
```

If you do a test of two binomial proportions in Python ScriPy, it
will almost surely give a slightly different P-value, but I suppose
not enough difference in computation to change the interpretation of
the test.

**For metric 2:**

I am not sure what you mean by "revenue per visitor."
Clearly, visitors who do not make purchases do not contribute to revenue.
So if we are looking at a value of the 'metric' for each *visitor,* there will be lots of $0$'s.

By contrast, if you compute revenue per visitor for each *day* or *week* in the
periods before and after your change, then the there will be a different
distribution for your metric (for one thing there will likely be fewer $0$'s, if any).  Maybe it would be better to look at
revenue per *buyer,* which seems (to me) to be easier to interpret.

One would have to take a look at the distributions of metric 2
values before and after your change to make a responsible decision what
kind of test is appropriate. Perhaps a two-sample Wicoxon test, a two-sample Welch t test, or something different from either. If neither of these tests
is appropriate, then a permutation test or a bootstrap confidence interval for the difference between before and after might be appropriate.

Comment: I am slightly confused by what you written in some paragraphs. It seems you are assuming a before vs after trial (which all of the caveats you've written on drift in metric, before and after chance, etc., then makes perfect sense), though I've never seen an AB experiment (or A/B test) referred as such in experimentation on the Web - the term almost always referred to a randomised controlled trial-style experiment. Am I missing something here?